# Why dot net bundle exited with code -2147450730 on Publish

Tags: publish, dotnet-bundle

I am trying to publish a website in VS2019 and it fails with

```
The command "dotnet bundle" exited with code -2147450730.
```

I haven't found much on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The build output window should have detailed information on the error:

```
Build started...
1>It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
1>The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0-preview1-002111-00' (x64) was not found.
1>  - The following frameworks were found:
1>      6.0.2 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
1>
1>You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
1>
1>The specified framework can be found at:
1>  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=2.0.0-preview1-002111-00&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
```

After I installed the missing framework it worked for me: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=2.0.0-preview1-002111-00&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64